# How to get GTK syntax highlighting in GEdit?

Tags: c, gtk, gedit

I just started using GTK to develop my GUI applications. I'm using GEdit as my text-editor, so how can I get the following to be included in the syntax highlighting:

```
GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button
GtkWidget *box1;

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
```

as if it were like this:

```
int x = 3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend Gedit's syntax with a .lang file which contains XML:
http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtksourceview-2.0/stable/lang-tutorial.html
http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtksourceview-2.0/stable/lang-reference.html

So you could change your C language file to add GTK+ data types. It wouldn't surprise me that someone already wrote it, though.

Comment: You can look for which languages are supported both in [the main gtksourceview list](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtksourceview/tree/data/language-specs) and in the ["extra language definitions list"](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GtkSourceView/LanguageDefinitions?action=show&redirect=GtkSourceView%2FLanguageDefinitions).